# Solve equation which is in string format

Tags: java, expression, expression-evaluation

I have a equation in string format like "45+5*4-6" which I have to solve in Java.

Is there any way to solve equation which is in string format?

Comment: You might use the `ScriptEngine` as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).

Comment: Or even this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3423360/2024761).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/)

Something like this should work -

```
Interpreter ip = new Interpreter();
ip.eval("res = 45+5*4-6");
System.out.print(ip.get("res"));
```